# Django tests failing on invalid keyword argument

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing

I have a models.py like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey('tool.product')
    module = models.ForeignKey('tool.module')
    model = models.ForeignKey('tool.model')
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

And my tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
# --- import app models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tool.models import Module, Model, Product
from user_profile.models import Project, UserProfile


# --- unit tests --- #
class UserProjectTests(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['admin_user.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.product1 = Product.objects.create(
            name='bar',
        )
        self.module1 = Module.objects.create(
            name='foo',
            enable=True
        )
        self.model1 = Model.objects.create(
            module=self.module1,
            name='baz',
            enable=True
        )
        self.user1 = User.objects.get(pk=1)

    ...

    def test_can_create_project(self):
        self.project1 = Model.objects.create(
            user=self.user1,
            product=self.product1,
            module=self.module1,
            model=self.model1,
            zipcode=90210
        )

        self.assertEquals(self.project1.zipcode, 90210)
```

But I get a `TypeError: 'product' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` error.

I'm not sure what is failing but I'm guessing something to do with the FK relationships...

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Full Traceback:

```
    ERROR: test_can_create_project (user_profile.tests.UserProjectTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sam/Dropbox/django-projects/unirac/user_profile/tests.py", line 52, in test_can_create_project
    zipcode=90210
  File "/home/sam/.envs/unirac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 137, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/sam/.envs/unirac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 375, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/home/sam/.envs/unirac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 367, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % kwargs.keys()[0])
TypeError: 'product' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback? (The lines before the error you pasted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Model.objects.create(`... should likely be `Project.objects.create(`

At:

```
self.project1 = Model.objects.create(
    user=self.user1,
    product=self.product1,
    module=self.module1,
    model=self.model1,
    zipcode=90210
)
```

---

On a sidenote, naming your `Model`, `Model`, as `from tool.models import Module, Model, Product` seems to imply, is *a bad idea*.

---

On another sidenote, the traceback usually provides *very* useful information as to where the error occured. Here, you can see that the traceback indicates the error occured in:

```
File "/home/sam/Dropbox/django-projects/unirac/user_profile/tests.py", line 52, in test_can_create_project
```

Before jumping to library code, which you can reasonably expect to not be buggy.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! Yes `Model` should have been `Project` which led me to more problems. self.user1 should actually be a `UserProfile` object. But now it works! Thanks again.

Comment: ...and yes. I guess I should rename the Model object, even though that is descriptive of the client's product.